# Invalid write of Size 8 when mallocing array of strings

Tags: c, string, shell, valgrind, strtok

I am trying to write my own Shell in C.  I have a problem.  I wrote my own _strtok function that uses strtok but returns all the tokens as an array of strings.  For testing I use the string "ls -laR" defined in the main function.  I get the valgrind error "Invalid write of size 8" when trying to malloc the number of chars in the second pointer in the array of strings named "Doubl".  Why is it doing this? I am allocating the proper number of pointers to strings in the doubl array.  Any insight or help would be appreciated

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
char **_strtok(char *str, char *delim)
{
        char **doubl;
        char *s = str;
        char *string;
        int i = 0;

        while (*s)
        {
                if (*s == *delim)
                        i++;
                s++;
        }
        doubl = malloc(sizeof(char *) * i + 1);
        i = 0;
        string = strtok(str, delim);
        while (1)
        {
                doubl[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(string) + 1);
                strcpy(doubl[i], string);
                i++;
                if (string == NULL)
                        break;
                string = strtok(NULL, delim);
        }
        return (doubl);
}

char *get_path(char **env)
{
        char **check = env;
        char *path = NULL;
        char  pth[] = "PATH";
        int i, j, stop = 0;

        for (i = 0; check[i] && stop == 0; i++)
        {
                for (j = 0; j < 4 && stop == 0; j++)
                {
                        if (check[i][j] != pth[j])
                                break;
                        if (check[i][j] == pth[j] && j == 3)
                        {
                                path = malloc(strlen(check[i]));
                                strcpy(path, check[i]);
                                stop = 1;
                        }
                }
        }
        return (path);
}

char **cmd_to_arg(char **cmd, char **env)
{

        /* FREE PATH BEFORE END */
        char *path = get_path(env);
        char *slash = "/";
        char **args = NULL, **check = _strtok(path, ":"), **checkStart = check, **cmdStart = cmd;
        int status = -1, i = 0, j;

        while (*checkStart)
        {
                strcat(*checkStart, slash);
                strcat(*checkStart, cmd[0]);
                status = access(*checkStart, F_OK | X_OK);
                printf("%s\n", *checkStart);
                if (status == 0)
                        break;
                checkStart++;
        }
        for(;*cmdStart; i++, cmdStart++)
                printf("%d\n", i);
        args = malloc(sizeof(char *) * i);
        args[0] = malloc(strlen(*checkStart));
        strcpy(args[0], *checkStart);
        puts(args[0]);
        for (j = 1; j < i && cmd[j] != NULL; j++)
        {
                //printf("%d\n", j);
                args[j] = malloc(strlen(cmd[j]) * sizeof(char));
                strcpy(args[j], cmd[j]);
                puts(args[j]);
        }
        return (args);
}

int main(int ac, char **av, char **env)
{
        (void)ac, (void)av, (void)env;
        char line[] = "ls laR";
        //size_t size = 0;
        char **cmd; //**cmdStart;
        //int i = 0, j = 0;

        cmd = _strtok(line, " ");
        cmd = cmd_to_arg(cmd, env);
        return (0);
}
```

Comment: How many pointers do you write to doubl? i+1? doubl is only big enough for i pointers plus one extra byte.

Comment: _Side note:_ In `_strtok`, `if (*s == *delim)` only checks the current char of string `s` against the _first_ delimiter [the other delimiters are _not_ checked]. So, passing `" "` works, but `" \t"` [or `" ,"`] would _not_

Comment: The code in `cmd_to_arg` expects a `NULL` terminator at the end of `check` [just like `argv`]. But, `_strtok` does _not_ allocate space for it, nor does it set it

Comment: And `doubl = malloc(sizeof(char *) * i + 1);` is too short. Because of operator precedence, this is equivalent to: `doubl = malloc((sizeof(char *) * i) + 1);` What you want is: `doubl = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (i + 1));`

Comment: But, that still doesn't provide space for the `NULL`, so you want: `doubl = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (i + 2));` And, you want: `doubl[i] = NULL;` at the end of the function.